# com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException

Tags: db2

I have installed DB2 on my local machine and created a table Users with a column Name.

From my portlets I am executing a simple select statement:

```
    Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
    String dburl = "jdbc:db2://localhost:50001/Portlets";
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl,"db2admin","password");
    String selectTableSQL = "SELECT Name from Users";
    statement = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(selectTableSQL);
```

when i execute this i get the following exception:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=DB2ADMIN.USERS, DRIVER=3.62.56.
```

I dont understand why I am getting this exception. There is nothing much in the stack trace as well.

Answer (score 3):

The `SQLCODE` in your message is what tells you the actual error message. `-204` is the error you are looking for. If you cross-reference the [Information Center article about `-204`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00204n.html), you will see the following message:

> *name* is an undefined name.

And if you look back at your exception, you see *name* = `DB2ADMIN.USERS` (the `SQLERRMC` field).

My guess is that you aren't finding anything because you forgot to append a Schema to your table (the `DB2ADMIN` part was assumed in the error message because that's your login name).

Comment: I actually resolved the issue. Its strange that I craeted a table with my domain name Sachin.Jain but then I granted all the permissions to db2admin like select insert sql commands and even then it was not able to access the database. So i finally logged in with db2admin user and then created the table and it worked.